# Adding footer for printing web pages and setting margins without media print

Tags: html, css, printing, media

How can set bottom margin for web page without using class when document print.
for some reason i can not create document head. i cant use code something like this because i have no access to head of document.

> ```
> @media print {
>     p.note {
>         bottom: 0; position: fixed; 
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't, or, for some reason, don't want to use css @media, you can always use some jquery:

```
window.onafterprint = function() {
    $("p.note").css("position","fixed");
    $("p.note").css("bottom","0");
}; // IE5+

window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(change) {
    if !(change.matches) {
        $("p.note").css("position","fixed");
        $("p.note").css("bottom","0");
    }
});  // Chrome 9+, Safari 5.1+
```

Here you can find some more info: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

And also there nearly exists a plugin: https://code.google.com/p/jmediatype/

Comment: unfortunately i can not use any script too.